# `mouse-1` (button 1) follows links, like `mouse-2` does - how to modify the behavior?

Tags: mouse, hyperlinks

I'm a beginner in Emacs.

In dired+, if I query the mouse click on a directory item with `C-h k`, I get the following:

```
----------------- up-event (short click) ----------------

<mouse-2> at that spot is remapped to <mouse-2>, which runs the
command dired-mouse-find-file-other-window, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `dired+.el'.

...

----------------- up-event (long click) ----------------

Pressing <mouse-1> at that spot for longer than 450 milli-seconds
runs the command mouse-set-point, which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function in `mouse.el'.
```

Can I set these "short" and "long" clicks somewhere? I couldn't find anything about mouse-up events; is this specific to dired+? Also, it seemed to me that the short click is mapped to `mouse-2` somehow; if I set `mouse-2`, then the `mouse-1` short click changed accordingly. I find this a bit annoying though, because I can't set `mouse-2` and the `mouse-1` short click to different commands. I'd like to also be able to set them differently.

Comment: Yes, I too would find it annoying. As soon as this "feature" was imposed on Emacs as the default behavior (in order to match behavior outside Emacs, in particular in web browsers) I removed it (for myself), by customizing option `mouse-1-click-follows-link` to `nil`. Emacs used to use only `mouse-2` for following links, and it used `mouse-1` for setting point etc. (And for me it still does.) And with no monkeying around with delays. Just set the option to `nil`, if you want to return to that simple, sane, "classic Emacs" behavior.

Comment: This is not specific to Dired+ or to Dired. I've edited your question title accordingly (but I left the question body as it was).

Answer (score 4):

You want to look at `C-h v mouse-1-click-follows-link RET`, I think.